# How to capture mew in UnovaRpg?

Tags: unova-rpg

I know where to find Mew. I attack mew to get his HP lower, and as soon as I throw a pokeball to capture him, he seems to run away. It shows the Pokémon wasn't caught.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a masterball instead of pokeball.

**Legendary pokemons can only be captured using Masterball.**